# ArcMap Input Parameter Character Limit

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am currently running some tests with a large JSON data string. I suspect that there might be a character limit where you can add input parameters but I am not sure. Is there a character limit for a string in ArcMap? This is json data I pulled from a GeoProcesssing Server.
Here is what I am talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TwFm.jpg

Comment: It's saying the limit is 29999, this must be a lib limit as a python string can be **very** long, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string. In the lib that the python calls the input must be (in C) char* InputLabelName = new char[299999]; which would be limiting the string... I have encountered this before and it was not python that was limiting the string.

Comment: This may or may not be related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19721/sending-long-json-objects-polygon-geometry-table-rows-in-post-request-to-geop

Comment: There's no practical limit on python strings. ArcGIS is limiting the tool inputs to 30K characters.  Your JSON parsing is failing because it's getting a truncated string. Workaround, write json string to temp file, pass that to the tool and load that.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/130349/2856

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the suggestion, but this string will change. I looked at the link that both PolyGeo and you sent. They answer part of my question but how would I run my script from command line or somewhere else?

Comment: The 30k caharacter limitation only applies when running the tool from ArcGIS Desktop.  When the tool is published as a GP tool, it can handle longer strings.