# Is there a size limit when adding features to ArcGIS Server programatically using POST?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I'm inserting new points using the ArcGIS Server REST API [addFeatures](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/fsadd.html) method - this is working correctly.

However, I'm finding that when the JSON reaches a certain (undefined) threshold the POST fails with a 404. If the JSON is reduced in size the (otherwise identical) POST succeeds.

I can't see any inherent limits in Python's `request` functionality. **Is this a known limitation with the ArcGIS Server REST API, or are there any workarounds?**

Below is some code to reproduce the problem, using a sample Esri server so you can test it.

The target field has a width of 60 so it's expected that the insertion will return an error message with a string 1000 characters long. But note that it errors with a 404 when the string is 3000 characters long.

```
import json, requests

for num in [10, 1000, 3000]:

    # The following works with 10, gives a legitimate error with 1000, and gives a 404 with 3000
    value = "a" * num

    data = [{"attributes": {'address': value}, "geometry": {"x": 0,"y": 0 }}]
    params = {"f": "json","features": json.dumps(data)}
    headers = {'content-type':'application/json','Accept':'application/json'}
    response = requests.post("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures", headers=headers, params=params)
    print("With number = " + str(num) + " the response is " + response.text)
```

Results:

> With number = 10 the response is
> {"addResults":[{"objectId":18209901,"globalId" :
> null,"success":true}]}
>
> With number = 1000 the response is
> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete
> operation.","details":["Unable to add features"]}}
>
> With number = 3000 the response is  404 - File or directory not found.

Why does posting the long JSON string return a 404, and how can this be resolved?

Comment: It's too long ago for me to remember the details but I have a suspicion that you may be striking a limit of 1024 on a URL.  I got past it here with help from Jason Scheirer and Paul Cavallaro: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19721/how-to-send-long-json-objects-polygon-geometry-table-rows-in-post-request-to

Comment: @polygeo thanks for the tip - but I think _take the query (everything after the ?) and jam it in the data argument_ is basically what I've done by sending the object as `params=params`, which contains `json.dumps(data)`? PS I've updated the code so you can verify this

Comment: When I POST in JavaScript, the data goes as data, not parameters (POST can have both). Use your browser diagnostic to see what is actually being sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SampleServer3 = ArcGIS 10.0.

SampleServer6 = 10.3.

As suggested, its the **server** which is having problems, not your code.
The following works against 10.3 - note I modified your code to use built-ins instead of `Requests`. (Remember, Server underwent massive changes between 10.0 and 10.1. If you're stuck at 10.0 I'd suggest looking to upgrade as soon as possible. You can see here that [10.0 has been retired](http://downloads.esri.com/support/product%20life%20cycle/arcgis_desktop/ArcGIS_PLC.pdf))

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

#url = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures"
url = "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/SF311/FeatureServer/1/addFeatures"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

for num in [10, 1000, 3000]:

    value = "a" * num
    data = [{"attributes": {'address': value}, "geometry": {"x": 0,"y": 0 }}]
    params = {"f": "json","features": data}

    req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(params).encode('UTF-8'), headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    response_text = response.decode('UTF-8')
    response_json = json.loads(response_text)
    print response_json
```

> {u'addResults': [{u'success': True, u'objectId': 29413}]}
>
> {u'addResults': [{u'success': True, u'objectId': 29414}]}
>
> {u'addResults': [{u'success': True, u'objectId': 29415}]}

Comment: Many thanks for this, it's exactly the sort of tweak I was hoping existed. (I'm actually using ArcGIS Online for this, so it's Server 10.3, but my original code sample failed there too)

Answer (score 1):

As @polygeo suggests, POST requests do have a size limit, but it depends on server and browser.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880777/3182496

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but are you positive that's what's happening here? It doesn't seem like that string would be anywhere near 2Gb. I've updated the question with a simpler sample to demonstrate the problem

Comment: I don't know, but POST does have some odd behaviour. I've had string parameters like "2.00" rounded and returned to me as a string of "2". There must be all kinds of "helpful" optimisations going on under the hood.